# Extracting corresponding row values of selected column(s) in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

[image]

*** Cx , Cy= Center (X coordinates , Y coordinates)

Row P , Col P = Row and Column Pixel values ***

Given a scenario like above, I wish to extract the corresponding *row* and *column* pixel values of the selected *cX* and *cY*.

Example: if cX value = (min(cX) +/- 10) ***and*** cY = (min(cY) +/- 10) then return the corresponding row and column pixel values.

Expected output: cX = 298 , cY = 270 RowP = 842, and ColP = 505

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is a numpy matrix called 'values':

```
cx_min = min(values[:, 1])
cy_min = min(values[:, 2])
for i in range(0, len(values[:, 1])):
    cx = values[i, 1]
    cy = values[i, 2]
    if cx in range(cx_min-10, cx_min+11):
            if cy in range(cy_min-10, cy_min+11):
                    rowp = values[i, 3]
                    colp = values[i, 4]
                    print(cx, cy, rowp, colp)
```

This prints:

```
(298.0, 270.0, 842.0, 505.0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much , I was thinking on the right path but just couldn't prepare the syntax :)